# How to set an existing IAM role to a new instance while spinning in terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to attach an existing role created in AWS, but I am not able to add it in Terraform Code. I tried to add the role in instance profile but it didn't work either for me.

Is there any direct way to add it in the resource in Terraform Code ?

*`iam_instance_profile  = "my-role"`*

> **Note:** my-role is having the full access of ec2.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: That should work, but like @PhilippClaßen said, without knowing what happened it's near impossible to help you out with this.

Comment: Look this post for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224781/3016764

Answer (score 1):

you can add role like below

```
role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_role_name.name}"
```

Please check - https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_instance_profile.html

Comment: Maybe you could link to some documentation to complete this answer, it's a bit terse as is

Comment: `role` is not a valid argument for the terraform resource aws instance -
 https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html

Comment: Please check this role is vaild   https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_instance_profile.html